# Return all nodes from my json with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, html

I have a JSON and I need the value of all the nodes. I'm tryint it but I just recieve the 1st and 2nd nodes. The 3rd node return me [Object Object]
Somebody Can help me?

My JSON it's like this:

```
{
    1: {
        NAME: "NAME1",
        EXTERNALID: "idExternal1",
        LINK: "mylink1",
        DESCRIPTION: "Description1",
        PRODUCT_TOP: {
            PRICE: 549,
            NAME: "PRODUCT_TOP NAME",
            LONGTDESCRIPTION: "LongDesc1",
            LINK: "http://myurl.com",
            PRICESRC: "http://myurl.com",
            SHORTDESCRIPTION: "Tu hogar puede estar a la temperatura perfecta para ti, con el aire acondicionado Panasonic KIT YE12 QKE ¡Entra y descúbrelo! ",
            PHOTO: "http://myurl.com"
        }
        },
        2: {
            NAME: "NAME2",
            EXTERNALID: "idExternal2",
            LINK: "",
            DESCRIPTION: "Description2",
            PRODUCT_TOP: {
                PRICE: 13.99,
                NAME: "PRODUCT_TOP NAME",
                LONGTDESCRIPTION: "LongDesc2",
                LINK: "http://myurl.com",
                PRICESRC: "http://myurl.com",
                SHORTDESCRIPTION: "The Simpsons.",
                PHOTO: "http://myurl.com"
            }
        }
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               }
```

My jQuery script is:

```
$.getJSON( "myjsonurl.json", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( i, val ) {
        items.push( "<li id='" + val + "'>" + i + ' / '+ val + "</li>" );
        $.each( val, function( x, val2 ) {
            items.push( "<li id='" + val2 + "'>" +x + ' / '+ val2 + "</li>" );
            $.each( val2, function( z, val3 ) {

                items.push( "<li id='" + val3 + "'>" +z + ' / '+ val3 + "</li>" );

            });
        });
    });

    $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( ".send" );
});
```

Are there anyone to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting "[Object Object]" is because you are converting an object to a string. I would check your code - but I imagine that your id at levels 1 and 2 would be wrong too.

There are a few approaches here - but I would go with a recursive system (no repeated code, and infinite depth) which checks for the presence of an object. Try this for size:

http://jsfiddle.net/7ewokumg/

```
var finalItems = [];

function printProperties(o) {

    //Iterate through properties    
    $.each(o, function (i,v) {
        //If it's an object - recursively work with it
        if (typeof v === "object") {
            printProperties(v);
        } else {
            //It's just a string
            finalItems.push("<li id='" + v + "'>" + i + ' / '+ v + "</li>" );
        }
    });        
}

//process our data to populate finalItems
printProperties(data);

//Add all the items to an unordered list
$("<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
     html: finalItems.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "body" );
```

Comment: Wooooow, it's a good solution. I'll go to try it with my JSON and tell you something.

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking to flatten and convert the JSON data you’re receiving to a string. This is a little bit of an abstraction from how you’re approaching it:

```js
function mapToLi(value, index) {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return '<li id="' + value + '">' + value + '</li>';
    }
    return $.map(value, mapToLi).join('');
}

function flatten( data ) {   
    $('.result').append($.map(data, mapToLi).join(''));
}

flatten({
    NAME: "NAME1",
    EXTERNALID: "idExternal1",
    LINK: "mylink1",
    DESCRIPTION: "Description1",
    PRODUCT_TOP: {
        PRICE: 549,
        NAME: "PRODUCT_TOP NAME",
        LONGTDESCRIPTION: "LongDesc1",
        LINK: "http://myurl.com",
        PRICESRC: "http://myurl.com",
        SHORTDESCRIPTION: "Tu hogar puede estar a la temperatura perfecta para ti, con el aire acondicionado Panasonic KIT YE12 QKE ¡Entra y descúbrelo! ",
        PHOTO: "http://myurl.com"
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
```